# Merge a specific number of cells based on a value in cell in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want if a value in sheet 2 cell A1 is "3" then in another worksheet merge cells C1, D1, and E1. If it is 5, then merge cells C1, D1, E1, F1, and G1.

---

I am trying to support my salesforce apex developer in doing some template tagging for report generation. Basically, it is passing some values into an excel spreadsheet and I am writing formulas on the excel spreadsheet to apply conditional formatting so the report will look as desired. I've hit a few roadblocks. Here is my first:

The program will pass in a specific number on sheet 2, cell A1 to determine how many columns there are. I found a way to number and highlight those columns, but not a way to adjust the row that is to be the heading of these columns that specifies the quote period (Weeks, Months, or Quarters). This heading by default was set to merge 10 cells across row C1 to L1. But if there are, say 6 columns, then this merge needs to be adjusted to include cells across 6 rows, C1 to H1. Or if it ends up being 18 columns, then the header row needs to span 18 rows, from C1 to T1. From reading up on previous questions regarding Excel-VBA and cell merges, I know some people are going to say "you shouldn't do that." Unfortunately, I haven't much of a choice. This is the approved format.

So, I want to do this leaving the cells unmerged so that the named cell C1 is going to be the one it looks for to drop the quote period name into. I've looked at the code here.

https://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-merge-cells/

```
Sub mergeCells()
    Worksheets("Merge Cells").Range("A5:E6").Merge
End Sub
```

That assumes you know the beginning and end of what you want to merge. My merge cells statement needs to look something like:

```
    Worksheets("Merge Cells").Range("C1:π").Merge
```

Where π is the number of spaces to the right of C1. It looks like the 5th example at this webpage is probably the one I want:

```
With Worksheet

    For Counter = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1

        If .Cells(Counter, CriteriaColumn).Value = Criteria Then .Range(.Cells(Counter, FirstColumn), .Cells(Counter, LastColumn)).Merge

    Next Counter

End With
```

The value passed is on the second worksheet. What is the change I need to make this work?

Comment: Maybe it's the Friday thing but I'm struggling to understand what it is that you are asking.. are you saying you want to know how to merge some cells based on the value provided in another sheet, starting from `[C1]`?

Comment: Zac - Thanks for your reply! That's exactly it. So If that value in sheet 2 cell A1 is "3" then it will merge C1, D1, and E1. If it's 5, then it will merge C1, D1, E1, F1, and G1. So forth.

Comment: Try `sheet1.range("a1").resize(,sheet2.range("A1").value).merge`

Comment: Holy shnikes that worked! except I used "sheet1.range("C1") because that's where i wanted it to start, but that's so great thank you!